# Limiting jobs using Quartz Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz Scheduler to schedule jobs. This is my quartz.properties file thread count:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 2
```

I had scheduled 8 jobs to run at a particular time, but the problem is all the jobs are running at one time. This shouldn't happen because my thread count is 2; only 2 jobs should run and the others should be in a waiting state.

Comment: Youre right, that shouldnt happen. How did you find out that 8 jobs 
ran simultaneously? Could you check your logfiles to determine whether quartz uses a ThreadPool of size 2 (that should appear in the logs right after the scheduler is started)?